# Monte Carlo simulation of a dice

Tags: dice, monte-carlo

> In MC simulation of a fair die the random numbers $x_n$ are generated
> between $0$ and $3$. Then which one denotes the event of obtaining $1$
> in dice?
>
> 1. $0<x_n<\dfrac 16$
> 2. $0<x_n<1$
> 3. $\dfrac 13<x_n<1$
> 4. $0<x_n<\dfrac 12$

I'm stuck finding this solution. How are the random numbers generated and how do they represent any sort of event of rolling a dice? Help me to find this solution.

Comment: Apparently they are are uniform in $[0,3]$

Comment: @user619894 sorry! didn't get you

Comment: the random numbers are seleted uniformly in the range between 0 and 3.

Comment: @user619894 then how does a number in $(0,3)$ represent getting a side of the dice? How do I find the probability of getting $1$ in one roll?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: If you roll an actual die, what is the probability it comes out $1$? If you generate a uniformly distributed random real number $x$ with $0 \le x \le 3$, what is a range of values for $x$ which will have the same probability for $x$ lying in that range as the probability of rolling a $1$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair the probability of getting 1 is $\frac 16$. Now if I generate random number between 0 and 3, the seed being of 1 digit (I don't know if a seed can be a non integer), all the random numbers will be 0. So obtaining 0 is a sure event and $\frac 16$ cannot be obtained

Comment: @PaulSinclair none of the options except (2) and (4) includes the probability $\frac 16$. But (4) being subset of (2), is (4) the correct option?

Comment: Whether you can use non-integers as a seed is going to depend on the particular psuedo-random umber generator you are using. But here is an extremely important bit of advice on using any random number generator: DON"T USE A TINY NUMBER AS A SEED! Most commonly, the original seed is going to be time in milliseconds since some epoch (fixed datetime such as midnight Jan 1, 1970). This is done because the exact starting seed has some randomness built into it, based on whenever the program was run.

Comment: Now I have run into a pseudo-random integer generator before that allowed you to set a range and used the output in that range as its seed for the next number. If that is what you have, then I have a second bit of advise: discard it and find one not written by an idiot.  A good pseudo-random number generator will always generate its seed numbers in as wide a range as it can. Only the result reported to you will be transformed into your required range. If you are only getting $0$ out of a "random number generator", then you are not getting random numbers.

Comment: Yes, the probability you need to obtain is $\frac 16$. Now you are generating *real* numbers between 0 and 3. If you don't do something stupid in generating these numbers, they should be equally distributed across that range, which has width $3$. To simulate your die, you need to break that range up into $6$ sub-ranges, representing the six possible values of the die. Each of the subranges should be sized so that all of them have an equal possibility of the generated number falling in them. What width of subrange do you think will be needed?

Comment: @PaulSinclair each subrange should be of length $\frac 12$. And the probability $\frac 16$ falls in the subrange $(0,\frac 12)$. So I think (4) is the correct option. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is the only option that covers $\frac 16$ the range of the simulated values.